# listbox with checked radio button in windows application?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, webforms

I want to know what is the tool that can I use from toolbox to make multi selected from list box with checked radio button like shown in the image because if I choose listbox normally and made selection mode 'multiple' it must choose with Ctrl to choose multiple.

[image]

Comment: CheckedListBox?

Comment: RTM? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist(v=vs.110).aspx